# how to instantiate words letter by letter to grid without the words being cut

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game where the player will solve a phrase just like in the wheel of fortune minus the wheel but the problem is some words are being cut out when the word exceeds the 15 column. is there any way make the word full into the next row?

i only tried it with what i know making a tile for each letter

i cant seem to find any solution for this on the net, and i only started learning unity

```
private const int Columns = 15;
private const float Space = 35.0f;
public void LettertoBox()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < currentWord.Length; i++)
    {
        int row = i / Columns;
        int column = i % Columns;


        Vector3 newPosition3;
        newPosition3 = new Vector3((cen.transform.position.x + column * Space), (((cen.transform.position.y )) - row * Space), cen2.transform.position.z);

        if (currentWord[i].ToString() != " ")
        {
            GameObject k = (GameObject)Instantiate(letterimage, newPosition3, Quaternion.identity);
            k.name = "letterimage" + (i + 1);
            k.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("Canvas").transform);
        }
        else
        {
            GameObject k = (GameObject)Instantiate(noletterimage, newPosition3, Quaternion.identity);
            k.name = "letterimage" + (i + 1);
            k.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("Canvas").transform);
        }

        GameObject l = (GameObject)Instantiate(letter, newPosition3, Quaternion.identity);
        l.name = "letter" + (i + 1);
        l.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("Canvas").transform);   
    }
}
```

**Actual result**

[image]

**Expected result**

[image]

Comment: Surely when looking at a new word, check the number of spaces left, if less than length of word, new line

Comment: @BugFinder can i have an example code of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you as long as no word in the phrase is too big for the line (in which case you just need to identify it and split it with '-')

```
public void LetterToBox() {
    int rowCount = 0;
    int position = 0;
    foreach (string word in phraseToSplitToWords.Split(" ")) {
        if (CannotFitWordWithoutCuttingPastTheLimit(position,word, whateverIsTheNumberOfLettersPerLineYouWant)) {
            rowCont++;
            position= 0;
        }
        PlaceTheWordLetterByLetterInThisPosition(position,row,word);
        position = position + word.Length +1; //+1 for the space between words
    }
}

public void PlaceTheWordLetterByLetterInThisPosition(int positionInLine, int row, string word) {
    foreach (char letter in word) {
        var x = positionInLine* LETTER_WIDTH;
        var y = row* LETTER_HEIGHT;
        InstantiateLetter(x, y, letter); //basically the same way you did

    }
}


public bool CannotFitWordWithoutCuttingPastTheLimit(int position, string word, int limit) {
    return (position + word.Length > limit);
}
```

Comment: i dont know how to make this part work InstantiateLetter(x, y, letter); they're stacking to each other when i do it like this Instantiate(letter, newPosition3, Quaternion.identity);

Comment: can you debug and check which values "newPosition3" has? you may need to also pass them the background as a parent

Comment: i added positionInLine++; to make the x move and it worked, thank you!